# Failing to replicate the signal-to-noise ratio from original lasso paper

Tags: regression, lasso, reproducible-research

I'm referencing example 1 under the simulations section from [Tibshirani](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf).

In short there's a model in the form
$$
y = \beta^Tx + \sigma \epsilon,
$$
where $\beta = (3, 1.5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0)^T$ and $\epsilon$ is standard normal. Correlations between $x_i$ and $x_j$ is $\rho^{|i - j|}$ with $\rho = 0.5$. $\sigma = 3$. My assumption from the beginning of the paper (standardizing variables) and [this presentation](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/lee.2272/882/yongganglasso.pdf) (normality) is that $x$ is standard normal with a variance-covariance matrix that is the same as the correlation matrix.

Using the formula
$$
SNR = \frac{\beta^T\Sigma\beta}{\sigma^2},
$$
taking $\Sigma$ to be the correlation matrix of $x$ and everything else given I find the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) to be around $2.36$ which less than half of the $5.7$ suggested in both the paper and the presentation.

What am I missing?

Comment: A factor of two by the looks of it.

Comment: It does seem the original paper has a typo. See this [code](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwDEDv@YpcBu1QpxUvY7/QHba7oK6oMNsS636/MwXHIJDk5SWEYuxN6PCW4yDqDKuiybBMoY6ilOBZeBs7hkmwL0EzcVswJMh4UWVe7ttXLxG04lnXr0JjjkFoKYEmx7AsGhjch8udtFqB3RZDXXDELL1yOp@QHc4MYJ3HJX1Yw8tYt8z28NOkVfC8P7j93br8eeBptkHsiozxCw)